# Trig substitution triangle restrictions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I apologize if this is a dumb question, or if I am a little slow, but I've been thinking about this for all of yesterday and today and I just can't figure it out, despite googling it.

I am confused about when we can use a triangle in trig substitution to redefine our expression in terms of other trig functions.

Take $x=\sin\theta$, $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for example.  If we draw a triangle we get the following information:

$\cos\theta = \sqrt{1-x^2}, \tan\theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

On the interval its clear to me that sine and tangent are the same, but sine and cosine are only the same for $x \ge 0$

**What if I have to solve a definite integral where I've made a cosine substitution with the bounds $a=-1$, $b=1$**

I can't do this because cosine and sine are only the same on $x\ge0$.  What do I do?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you include an example with your work including the problematic substitution.

Comment: I can't really find an example that I feel would better illustrate the difficulty I'm encountering.  My main issue is that when I graph the cosine function and sine function in my question, they only produce the same graph for $x \ge 0$.  Because of this fact, when we solve an integral with a cosine substitution  we have to restrict the domain of the answer to $x \in [0, 1]$ ?

Comment: i.e., the graph of $\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is clearly not the same as $\sin \theta=x$ on the interval $x \in [-1, 1]$  So when we solve an integral, how can we just make such a substitution without stating the answer is only valid for $x \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: What would happen if we inverted the portion of the cosine function on the interval $[-\pi,-\frac{\pi}{2}] \cup [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$?